# Expandablelistview group header Loses focus when clicked

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an expandablelistview that opens one group header at a time, that is, i close previously opened group header anytime i click a group header. Anytime i click a group header for the first time it behaves normally, but subsequent clicks on group header pushes the clicked group header away from view, to the top. How can i make the group header stay at the top?

```
list.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
         //   parent.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(groupPosition, 0);
            parent.setSelectionFromTop(groupPosition,0);

            return false;
        }
    });
    list.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {


        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                list.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use thel following code into your onGroupClick() method. Once I had solved this way. Hope it helps for you

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        parent.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(groupPosition, 0);
    }
},100);
```

Comment: thanks very much, it worked. how can i make the clicked header first in view.